# MKPointAnnotation tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Simple Question: Seems I cannot find the tag attribute for MKPointAnnotation class. It return error;

```
MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[HCIAnnotationViewController alloc]
                                     initwithHouse:house];
```

The following returns error (Property tag not found ob object of type "MKPointAnnotation"

```
NSLog(@"%d",annotation.tag);
```

My question is, if Im not allowed to set the tag, How am I supposed to detect which annotation was clicked.

The other approaches I followed are

**Setting tag for MkAnnotationView, However in this what I found out is that the last annotation when added doesn't immediately call for viewForAnnotation (Might be because I'm adding around 1000 MkPointAnnotations to a small map, so it only calls when it comes to view.).**

Please tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Since `MKPointAnnotation` is not a subclass of UIView, has not a property called tag. Bu you have the property coordinate. I assume you have different coordinates for all of your annotations. So you can detect which one.

You just need to compare the coordinates.